# Ошибка в использовании file_puts_contents()

Tags: php, json

Помогите найти Ошибку:

Php код:

```
 if(isset($_POST['strv'])){
    $idp = $_POST['strv'];
    $db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "testsite", "testsite", "LHVideo");
    $idp = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE id = '$idp'"))["id"];
    $date = date("Y-d-m H:i:s");
    $idv = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MAX(idv) AS max_idv FROM videos"))['max_idv'];
    $idv = $idv + 1;
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO videos (idv, idp, date) VALUES ('$idv', '$idp', '$date')");
    $e = mysqli_error($db);
    $src = $_POST['src'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $vname = $_POST['vname'];
    $arr = array(
        $idv => [
            "vname" => $vname,
            "src" => $src,
            "desc" => $desc
        ]
    );
    $arr = json_encode($arr);
        /*45 строка */ file_puts_contents("../json/videos.json", $arr);
    echo($idv);
    mysqli_close($db);
    exit();
}
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не puts, а put.....

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['strv'])){
    $idp = $_POST['strv'];
    $db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "testsite", "testsite", "LHVideo");
    $idp = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE id = '$idp'"))["id"];
    $date = date("Y-d-m H:i:s");
    $idv = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MAX(idv) AS max_idv FROM videos"))['max_idv'];
    $idv = $idv + 1;
    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO videos (idv, idp, date) VALUES ('$idv', '$idp', '$date')");
    $e = mysqli_error($db);
    $src = $_POST['src'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $vname = $_POST['vname'];
    $arr = array(
        $idv => [
            "vname" => $vname,
            "src" => $src,
            "desc" => $desc
        ]
    );
    $arr = json_encode($arr);
    /*45 строка */ file_put_contents("../json/videos.json", $arr);
    echo($idv);
    mysqli_close($db);
    exit();
}
```

Ошибка в названии функции.